# Changing font-weight to normal in h2

Tags: html, css

I Want to change font-weight to normal of h2 element. I'm trying to do it by change it in parent directory.

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top, .date {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.date {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: normal;  
}
```

```html
<div id="instrument" class="top">
  <h2>SP500</h2>
</div>
<div id="date" class="top date">
  <h2>Data</h2>
</div>
<div class="date">
  <h2>Czas Zamknięcia</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: As you want to reflect the parent (div) element's `font-weight` to the child element `h2` just add `h2 {font-weight: inherit;}`. Here the `inherit` keyword inherits or applys what ever style its parent or ancester element has.

Comment: Note that the divs with `.top`, `.top.date`, and `.date` all have `font-weight: normal` because that is the default, so `h2 { font-weight: inherit; }` will make all three of the `<h2>`s normal weight. If it is only the h2 with a `.date` div you would want an explicit rule: `.date h2 { font-weight: normal; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by parent directory, I guess you mean by selecting it with a parent tag/class/id, in that case, this is how you do it:

```
parent-tag h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

or if you want to do it by parent class/id name like this

```css
.className/#idName h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top, .date {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.date {
  
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: normal;  
}
   .date>h2 {
  
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: normal !important;  
}
```

```html
<div id="instrument" class="top">
  <h2>SP500</h2>
</div>
<div id="date" class="top date">
  <h2>Data</h2>
</div>
<div class="date">
  <h2>Czas Zamknięcia</h2>
</div>
```